# Как запретить Apache веб-серверу показывать файлы, если нет index.html

Tags: apache

Я намеренно удалил index.html и получаю вот такой ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел получать 403 или 404. Как запретить такое поведение? Maybe директива какая-то?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно есть "какая-то директива". И описана она в совершенно неожиданном месте: аж в [документацию по настройке апача](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) запрятали, негодяи.